# sudo -E does not pass PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, linux, bash, sudo

I am trying to add a python path value to a different environment, as some script I run with another user needs it to be set.

Now, the weird thing is that when I run `sudo -E`, variables that  I have in my `env` do pass on to the user I'm `sudo`ing to- except that PYTHONPATH doesn't.

Running:

```
TESTVAR=testValue sudo -E bash -c 'echo $TESTVAR'
```

will print "testValue", but:

```
PYTHONPATH=testValue sudo -E bash -c 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

Won't print anything.

I'm trying to understand if there is anything special about specific variables, that sudo acts different with when passing them to a different environment.

Help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Output of `sudo -V` as root?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748045/sudo-e-option-does-not-work/18749090#18749090 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045539/scrapy-cannot-import-module-while-its-in-my-pythonpath/27523599#27523599

Answer (score 7):

Because `PYTHONPATH` is in the `sudo`'s Default table of "bad" variables to remove from the environment (if not kept explicitly with `env_keep`).

From `plugins/sudoers/env.c` file of `sudo` source code:

```
/*
 * Default table of "bad" variables to remove from the environment.
 * XXX - how to omit TERMCAP if it starts with '/'?
 */
static const char *initial_badenv_table[] = {
    "IFS",
    .
    . (Truncated)
    .
    "PYTHONHOME",               /* python, module search path */
    "PYTHONPATH",               /* python, search path */
    "PYTHONINSPECT",            /* python, allow inspection */
    "PYTHONUSERBASE",           /* python, per user site-packages directory */
    "RUBYLIB",                  /* ruby, library load path */
    "RUBYOPT",                  /* ruby, extra command line options */
    NULL
};
```

As you can see `PYTHONPATH` is right in there.

The compiled binary file that implements this on runtime is `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`.

Answer (score 0):

As [heemayl said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824788/sudo-e-does-not-pass-pythonpath/35825459#answer-35825397), `PYTHONPATH` and other variables that modify the behavior of programs (and that can be used to escalate privileges) are ignored by `sudo -E`.

To enable them you have two ways:

- Explicitly pass them as arguments to `sudo`, like this:

  ```
  sudo PYTHONPATH=... command
  ```
- Configure the `env_keep` variable of your sudoers file. For example:

  ```
  Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
  ```

  Note that this line, being part of `Defaults`, may apply to all sudoers, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo env "PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH" bash -c 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

You need `env` to force the passing.